# creating async and sync loggers on condition in log4j2

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2, apache-commons-logging

My log4j2.xml looks like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%sn] [%t] %-5level %logger{36}     - %msg%n" />
        </Console>

        <RandomAccessFile name="randomAccessFile" fileName="temp\\logs.log" immediateFlush="false" append="false">
            <!-- <PatternLayout pattern="%d %p %class{2.} [%t] %location %m %ex%n" /> -->
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
        </RandomAccessFile>

        <JDBC name="databaseAppender" tableName="app_logs" bufferSize="1000">
            <!-- <DataSource jndiName="java:/comp/env/jdbc/testLog" /> -->
            <!-- <BurstFilter level="TRACE" rate="20" maxBurst="2" /> -->
            <ConnectionFactory class="com.mc.loggerProvider.ConnectionFactory" method="getDatabaseConnection" />
            <Column name="LOG_ID" pattern="%u{TIME}" isUnicode="false" />
            <Column name="LOG_TIMESTAMP" isEventTimestamp="true" isUnicode="false" />
            <!-- <Column name="CORR_ID" pattern="%X{CORR_ID}" isUnicode="false" /> -->
            <Column name="LOG_LEVEL" pattern="%level" isUnicode="false" />
            <Column name="LOGGER_NAME" pattern="%logger" isUnicode="false" />
            <Column name="MESSAGE" pattern="%msg %ex{full}" isUnicode="false" />
            <!-- <Column name="EXCEPTION" pattern="%ex{full}" isUnicode="false" /> -->
        </JDBC>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="console" level="trace" includeLocation="false" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="console" />
        </Logger>
        <AsyncLogger name="asyncFile" level="trace" includeLocation="false" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="randomAccessFile" />
        </AsyncLogger>
        <Logger name="syncFile" level="trace" includeLocation="false" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="randomAccessFile" />
        </Logger>
        <AsyncLogger name="asyncDB" level="trace" includeLocation="false" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="databaseAppender" />
        </AsyncLogger>
        <Logger name="syncDB" level="trace" includeLocation="false" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="databaseAppender" />
        </Logger>
        <AsyncLogger name="asyncDBasyncFile" level="trace" includeLocation="false" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="databaseAppender" />
            <AppenderRef ref="randomAccessFile"></AppenderRef>
        </AsyncLogger>
        <Logger name="syncDBsyncFile" level="trace" includeLocation="false" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="databaseAppender" />
            <AppenderRef ref="randomAccessFile"></AppenderRef>
        </Logger>
        <Root level="info" includeLocation="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="console" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

As there are couple of loggers I have defined already for sync/async file/DB logging purpose. The problem which I am facing here when I want to use any of the loggers I cant define a name for those.

```
LogManager.getLogger("asyncDB") -- will give me logger with name asyncDB
```

However, the convention says to create loggers with class name as it will be easier to debug if you write %logger in logging output.

```
LogManager.getLogger(MyClass.class)
```

My requirement asks me to create a logger with class name however that should be asynchronous or synchronous based on users requirement.

I have created a small class name LogProvider having method registerFor which is again having arguments of type AppendersType. Below is the code.

```
public class LogProvider {

public static Logger registerFor(AppendersType type) {
    switch (type) {
        case DATABASE_ASYNC:
            return LogManager.getLogger("asyncDB");
        case DATABASE_SYNC:
            return LogManager.getLogger("syncDB");
        case FILE_ASYNC:
            return LogManager.getLogger("asyncFile");
        case FILE_SYNC:
            return LogManager.getLogger("syncFile");
        case FILE_DATABASE_SYNC:
            return LogManager.getLogger("syncDBsyncFile");
        case FILE_DATABASE_ASYNC:
            return LogManager.getLogger("asyncDBasyncFile");
        default:
            break;
    }
    return null;
}
```

I want to make use of asyncLoggers but having a name of class and not the name which is defined in XML file.

Comment: A few ideas come to mind. 1. You could [extend log4j2](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/extending.html) so that it can somehow dynamically select the appropriate logger based on some sort of lookup. 2. Leverage the [automatic reconfiguration](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#AutomaticReconfiguration) by changing the config file via File I/O at runtime.

Comment: 3. You could combine class name with an indicator like "ASYNC" for example com.my.package.myClass.ASYNC 4. Perhaps try changing system properties as mentioned in ["Making All Loggers Asynchronous"](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/async.html#AllAsync).

Comment: user requirement to choose sync or async logger is during the execution of application or before starting the application ?